# angularfxlayout div alignment issue

Tags: angular, flexbox, angular-flex-layout

I am trying to display cards in a grid with responsive layout where if necessary, the cards are 4 per row versus 3 per row and so on. I am using angularfxlayout for this, which works well, but the divs are not aligned between rows.

**Like this:**

[image]

**Desired output:**

[image]

**Here is my code:**

```
<div fxLayout fxFill fxLayoutAlign="space-around center">
<div fxLayout="row wrap" fxFlex="90%" fxLayout.lt-md="column" fxLayoutGap="2%" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let dinner of dinners">
        <mat-card class="card-picture" fxLayout="column" >
            <mat-card-title class="dinner-title-details">
              <span>{{dinner.title}}</span>        
            </mat-card-title>
            <mat-card-content>
                <img mat-card-image src="../assets/dinnersample.jpg">
            </mat-card-content>
            <mat-card-actions>
                <i class="fab fa-facebook facebook"></i>
                <i class="fab fa-twitter twitter"></i>
                <i class="fab fa-instagram instagram"></i>
            </mat-card-actions>
          </mat-card>
    </ng-container>  
  </div>
```

Is there any way I can make the cards be aligned vertically as well?
Thanks!

Comment: Hi,   can you also provide the css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did two things to make it work under firefox and chrome.

removing fxLayoutAlign="center center" and setting a fixed width on the image (the width i'm not 100% sure, but please verify, sometimes there were minuscule differences it seemed).  I also include a general reset of margin and padding but i guess you had this already.

please refer to this simplified stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yetkra?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html

As I dont have your CSS I dont know what else might be wrong.